# Using execl() for command line with >> redirection

Tags: c, exec, io-redirection

I want to do the linux command echo "text" >> file.txt with C function execl();

I tried

```
execlp("echo","echo", "something" ,">>" ,"test.txt" ,NULL);
```

but it's not working

Comment: You can't do redirection with `execlp`. It's a shell operation, not implemented by the kernel.

Comment: You need to open the file in your program, then use `dup2()` to connect `STDOUT_FILENO` to the open file descriptor.

Comment: Redirections with `>` and `>>` are a feature of the SHELL, like BASH. You can use the command `bash -c "echo echo something >> test.txt"`